# how to identify addresses on an ethernet frame

Tags: cisco, lan, wireshark, mpls-vpn

How can I identify the sender's address, the receiver and what type of message does the frame carry on its payload?

The frame looks like this:

```
FF FF FF FF FF FF 08 24 F5 CE D3 AC 08 06 00 01 08 00 06 04 00 01 08 24 F5 CE D3 AC 83 78 2A 7F 00 00 00 00 00 00 83 78 29 6F 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Comment: That doesn't look quite right. I think you have dropped a byte in the beginning. It probably has six bytes of `ff`, not the five you have shown. The first six bytes are the destination address, and `ff ff ff ff ff ff` as the first six bytes would be the broadcast address.

Comment: No. Leave it as hexadecimal.

Comment: Each byte is eight bits, and each hexadecimal character is four bits long, so `ff` represents one byte.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The first six octets are the destination address. Your example has the broadcast destination address.

The next six bytes are the source address. In your example: `0824:F5CE:D3AC`.

The next sequence of bytes can be confusing. If the next two bytes are `8100` you have a four-byte 802.1Q VLAN tag. Otherwise, the two bytes represent the EtherType or length. if the two bytes are `0600` or greater, they are the EtherType, otherwise it is the payload length If there is an 802.1Q tag, it will be inserted here, and it will be four bytes long. Your example has `0806` so the EtherType is ARP, meaning this is an ARP request.

After that, you have the payload, followed by a four-byte Frame Check Sequence.

There are many sources for this information, just search for `ethernet frame header`.